# Huge GIS data need to show on map using leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a huge GIS data in db. I am fetching this data and converting it into geoJson file before viewing the map. I am fetching all of the data to meet the requirements, which is taking a lot of time. Is there any way to load data for a particular map window which user is viewing, and only loading respective GIS data for the same window using the leaflet library?

In my case, I am using Google Maps to show parking slots (GIS data) of a country on a map.

Comment: You may want to pose this question to GIS SE: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write some piece of code to get only the specific data from server. See if below lines can help you

```js
//whenever a drag or zoom finish, trigger the function to get new data
map.on('dragend', getData);//leaflet event
map.on('zoomend', getData);//leaflet event 

function getData(){
    //get the extent of your window
    var minx = map.getBounds().getEast();
    var miny = map.getBounds().getSouth();
    var maxx = map.getBounds().getWest();
    var maxy = map.getBounds().getNorth();

    //trigger an ajax call to get data as per your extent
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url_like_a_php_service',
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //send your extent to service to get specific data, like below 
        data: 'minx=' + minx + '&miny='+miny+ '&maxx='+maxx+ '&maxy='+maxy,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //you may write code here like showing a gif on map
        },
        complete: function (response) {
            //pass data to another function to render on map
            renderDataonMap();
        }
    });
}
```